# (GETENV XXX) is not a Lisp string or pointer

Tags: common-lisp

I'm afraid of asking this kind of basic question.

I want to manage database config by ENV, but I get an error.

This is my code:

```
(defconfig :common
    `(:databases ((:maindb :mysql
                      :database-name (uiop:getenv "DATABASE_NAME")
                      :host (uiop:getenv "DATABASE_HOST")
                      :port (uiop:getenv "DATABASE_PORT")
                      :username (uiop:getenv "DATABASE_USERNAME")
                      :password (uiop:getenv "DATABASE_PASSWORD")))))
```

This is sbcl error:

```
 1(GETENV DATABASE_HOST) is not a Lisp string or pointer.
 2   [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]
 3
 4Restarts:
 5 0: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "hunchentoot-worker-127.0.0.1:57248" RUNNING {10026777C3}>)
 6
 7Backtrace:
 8  0: ((:METHOD CFFI:TRANSLATE-TO-FOREIGN (T CFFI::FOREIGN-STRING-TYPE)) (UIOP/OS:GETENV "DATABASE_HOST") #<unused argument>) [fast-method]
 9      Locals:
10        CFFI::OBJ = (UIOP/OS:GETENV "DATABASE_HOST")
11  1: (COM.HACKINGHAT.CL-MYSQL-SYSTEM::MYSQL-REAL-CONNECT #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X7FFFE0015E50) (UIOP/OS:GETENV "DATABASE_HOST") (UIOP/OS:GETENV "DATABASE_USERNAME") (UIOP/OS:GETENV "DATABASE_PASSWORD") (UIOP/O..
12      Locals:
13        CLIENT-FLAG = 0
14        DATABASE = (UIOP/OS:GETENV "DATABASE_NAME")
15        HOST = (UIOP/OS:GETENV "DATABASE_HOST")
16        MYSQL = #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X7FFFE0015E50)
17        PASSWORD = (UIOP/OS:GETENV "DATABASE_PASSWORD")
18        PORT = (UIOP/OS:GETENV "DATABASE_PORT")
19        UNIX-SOCKET = #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X00000000)
20        USER = (UIOP/OS:GETENV "DATABASE_USERNAME")
21  2: ((:METHOD COM.HACKINGHAT.CL-MYSQL-SYSTEM::CONNECT-TO-SERVER (COM.HACKINGHAT.CL-MYSQL-SYSTEM:CONNECTION-POOL)) #<COM.HACKINGHAT.CL-MYSQL-SYSTEM:CONNECTION-POOL {1008B324F3}>) [fast-method]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing [*commas*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dg.htm) before the parts that are to be evaluated:

```
(defconfig :common
    `(:databases ((:maindb :mysql
                           :database-name ,(uiop:getenv "DATABASE_NAME")
                           :host ,(uiop:getenv "DATABASE_HOST")
                           :port ,(uiop:getenv "DATABASE_PORT")
                           :username ,(uiop:getenv "DATABASE_USERNAME")
                           :password ,(uiop:getenv "DATABASE_PASSWORD")))))
```